# Can I train my non-dominant hand and make it dominant?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, human-genetics

Are our dominant limbs decided on birth or is there some way in which I can train my non-dominant hand and make it as coordinated as my dominant?

Comment: You can find science studies and less thorough reading material on that from google, including for becoming ambidextrous. i.e. scientific american suggests that: It is possible to train your nondominant hand to become more proficient. A concert pianist demonstrates superb skill with both hands, but this mastery is complementary rather than competitive. My maths teacher was obliged to write right handed since he was in school, even though he was left handed. We agreed he was the least legible of our teachers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course you can train yourself and make your non-dominant hand to be equal or even greater than your actual dominant handedness. Handedness is directly wired to the right/left hemisphere of your brain, so by training, you will actually re-wire your brain and acquire new pathways. It's a hard process in terms of breaking habits, otherwise, it's non-invasive and non-painfull, where most humans tend to give up before acquiring this skill justifying it as an unnecessary/low priority goal.

Handedness is not decided upon birth. It's gained in the earlier process (while a child is still in mother's womb) based on personal/individual preference (expressed by sucking a finger btw) toward right-handedness (90%) or left-handedness (9%), cross-dominance/ambidexterity (1%).

- https://youtu.be/DU3OdTLuHf0
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handedness
- https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/primer/traits/handedness